# Reverse facetime camera is inverted

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I use gpuimage to build a photography app. But when I select the front camera, the camera picture appears on the back is reversed (left, right)
Code here:

```
 stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack]; 
stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
filter = [[GPUImageRGBFilter alloc] init];

[stillCamera addTarget:filter];
GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[filter addTarget:filterView];

[stillCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Who can tell me what I'm having problems?
Thank very much!

Answer (score 5):

try this...

```
stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack]; 
stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
stillCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = NO;
stillCamera.horizontallyMirrorRearFacingCamera = NO;

filter = [[GPUImageRGBFilter alloc] init];

[stillCamera addTarget:filter];
GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[filter addTarget:filterView];

[stillCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Comment: Thank Dhara, but i do not found horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera and horizontallyMirrorRearFacingCamera.

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
[filterView setInputRotation:kGPUImageFlipHorizonal atIndex:0];
```

Comment: I found a property I suggest to use. Because if you switch front / back camera, using this method, you have to change also the setInputRotation. So, to reduce you code, you can add this code to your camera object (GPUImageVideoCamera): _stillCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = YES;

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can easily change the final image :

```
UIImage *finalImage = //image from the camera

UIImage * flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:finalImage.CGImage scale:finalImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set:

```
stillCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = YES;
```

will fix this problem.